# Differences between Win2008 32 and 64 bit?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, sql-server-2008

I've been developing an asp.net (MVC) web-based app, using Windows 2003 Server and SQL Server 2005.  Now the client has decided to deploy to production on Windows 2008 Server and SQL Server 2008.

Are there any differences that I'll need to be aware of?  Does it make a difference if the database is Win2008 64bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your app needs to access the program files folder (which has `(x86)` appended to it when installing 32-bit apps on 64-bit windows) I don't think there will be any differences that affect the core ASP.NET code.

There may be some differences between SQL 2005 and 2008 that affect you but from what I've heard it is a much less disruptive upgrade than 2000 to 2005 was.  You can always try [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+2005+to+2008+differences) if you're really worried.

Even if you wind up installing a 32-bit version of SQL Server on 64-bit Windows (not that I would recommend such a thing) it'll probably work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in regards to the database. MS SQL Server is transparent when it comes to platform in this case. If you want to know about the asp end of things, you'll need to ask on SO.